# How to sort List Data in python with multiple parameters while givin a weight to the parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, subprocess

```
ListData= sorted(ListData, key=lambda x: ((x['AvailableOffers']  ['ValidTill'], x['AvailableOffers']['Amount'])), reverse=True)[:10]
```

Giving a weight to the params, I mean for example the statement above has two conditions for sorting, VALID TILL AND AMOUNT.
LETTING THE USER provide percentages for example
VALID TILL: 40%
AMOUNT: 60%

so is there anyway I can customize the sorting functions or is there any algorithms for multiple rankings I can consider??

Comment: What exactly do the weights do in the sorting?

Comment: Do you mean to filter by then sort or is the percentages supposed to be some threshold for sorting?

Comment: [:10] as you can see the statements returns only the top ten which is sorted by two conditions, so what i want is if the user says i need 60% on one parameter that params to take 6 of the returning elements and 4 to the other one!

Comment: @Lucas having multiple conditions in a sorting funtion results only in random result, i am not that sure though how that function works with multiple conditions is there any solution you can think of?, thanks

Comment: @StevenSummers nothing to filter just sort but with multiple conditions which has weight

Comment: The only thing I can think of is sort then grab first 10, grab first X from that, sort remaining slice from X to 10 by 2nd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the 4 and 6 amounts you mentioned in the post, you could do the following:

```
valid_till_list = sorted(
    ListData,
    key=lambda x: x['AvailableOffers']['ValidTill'],
    reverse=True,
)
amount_list = sorted(
    valid_till_list[4:],
    key=lambda x: x['AvailableOffers']['Amount'],
    reverse=True,
)
final_list = valid_till_list[:4] + amount_list[:6]
```

Comment: Thanks Man! but dont you think this way can cause duplicate ?

Comment: @MUHAMMAD this is why you sort `valid_till_list[4:]` when assigning to `amount_list`. That means the first 4 elements of that list won't be present in `amount_list`

Comment: @Lucas I think you want `valid_till_list` to be `[:10]` of the sorted list.

Comment: if the params more than 3, how can avoid duplicates: @Lucas        
        lp_list = sorted(
        ListData,
        key=lambda x: x['Participants'],
        reverse=False,
         )
        a_list = sorted(
        lp_list[lpScore[0]:],
        key=lambda x: x['AvailableOffers']['Amount'],
        reverse=True,
         )
        validity_list = sorted(
        a_list[mqScore[0]:], 
        key=lambda x: x['AvailableOffers']['ValidTill'],
        reverse=True,
         )
        ListData_by_Validity =  lp_list[:lpScore[0]] + a_list[:mqScore[0]] + validity_list[:mvScore[0]]

Comment: your version works fine withoud duplicates when the params are just two(valid_till_list, amount_list)but my version results duplicates, can you tell a way to avoid it ?@Lucas

Answer (score 0):

This post should be in the form of a comment to your question, since it is a request to you for clarifying your post more. But I have not got enough reputation, so it appears here.

The first thing is that [function sorted](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#sorted) take an [iterable](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator), such as *list, array, and string* as parameter. It seems that your `ListData` is a *dictionary*. So it is a must that you need to convert your data to appropriate form first.

What is the final formula of which `x[][ValidTill]`, `x[][Amount]`, and their `percentage` are parameters? For example, do you mean **sum** of them ? If yes, then below are the procedure:

```
# python ver 3.5. Note that the below code need to be adjusted 
# a little bit to be able to run on python 2.x.

import random

ListData = {
'AvailableOffers': {
    'ValidTill': [random.randint(1,10) for i in range(100)],
    'Amount': [random.randint(1,10) for i in range(100)]
}}

# Convert from dictionary to list
ListDataIter = list(zip(ListData['AvailableOffers']['ValidTill'], ListData['AvailableOffers']['Amount']))

# Now let have the percentage parameter inputted by users
FirstParam, SecondParam = 0.4, 0.6

# Sorting ListDataIter
sorted(ListDataIter, key=lambda x: x[0] * FirstParam + x[1] * SecondParam, reverse=True)[:10]

[(10, 10),
 (10, 10),
 (9, 10),
 (9, 10),
 (9, 10),
 (10, 9),
 (7, 10),
 (7, 10),
 (8, 9),
 (9, 8)]
```